# How to load multiple files present in different locations into pyspark dataframe at one go

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

is there a way that i can load multiple files into pyspark dataframe (2.0.0) at one go. These files are present in different directories. Or may be I can put it this way, I have a file stored in S3 with partitions on dayserial numeric (20161109) and I want to load data for specific dates(not all files inside the folders). Loading one by one and doing unionAll is not efficient (I beleive). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1) Rename all directories to pattern field=value, for example `day=20161109`, `day=20161110` and so on. Then use `spark.read` on parent directory and this `day` field will appear as extra column, co you can use it in `where` like this: `spark.read.parquet('/path/to/parent/dir').where(col('day').between('20161109', '20161110')`

2) Use [Hadoop glob pattern](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) and add all paths in form `{path1.path2}`, for example: `spark.read.parquet('/path/to/{20161109,20161110}')`.